# Rails - Silmple Form calls a specified action of my user controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, simple-form-for

My problem is that when i try to call a specified method from a simple_form_for form it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, :url => {:action => :register_iban}, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %> 
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <%= f.input :first_name, :label => t('user-show.payment.form.first_name'), placeholder: "Prénom" %>
                        <%= f.input :last_name, :label => t('user-show.payment.form.last_name'), placeholder: "Nom" %>
                        <%= f.input :iban, :label => t('user-show.payment.form.iban'), placeholder: "IBAN" %>
                        <%= f.input :bic, :label => t('user-show.payment.form.bic'), placeholder: "BIC" %>
                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                    <%= f.submit t('user-show.payment.title'), class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

So, as you can see, i try to call register_iban method from my user controller. 
But when i do that, i have an error : No route matches {:action=>"register_iban", :controller=>"users", :id=>"5", :locale=>nil}

Everytime i create a new method in a controller, i have to create a route in the routes.rb file ? Here, i'd like to make this url : /users/5/register_iban (where "5" is the user id) call my method.

Sorry but i start in ruby and i'm pretty stuck :/

Comment: Can you update your question with `routes.rb` code?

Comment: Yes, you must have a route for each controller action. There are different ways to do this, and here is a great article on this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

in your `config/routes.rb` try to add in the users resources

```
resources users do
  member do
    post :register_iban
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> No route matches {:action=>"register_iban", :controller=>"users", :id=>"5", :locale=>nil}

This error means you're trying to access a route which doesn't exist.

The *routes* are defined at `config/routes.rb`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   post :register_iban
end
```

This will allow you to call the `register_iban` method in the `users` controller through your form.

You'll also want to make sure you're calling routes with the appropriate helpers:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: user_register_iban(@user) %>
```